# Why does using parseInt on Error return 14?

Tags: javascript, parseint

Consider the following:

```
parseInt(new Array(), 10); // -> NaN
parseInt(new Array(), 16); // -> NaN

parseInt(new Error(), 10); // -> NaN
parseInt(new Error(), 16); // -> 14
```

It seems this behavior is unique to Error/instances of Error.  Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: Firstly, why using parseInt on Error?

Comment: `parseInt(["E"], 16)` works just as well.

Comment: Similarly, `parseInt(false, 16)` yields 250 (hexadecimal FA).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, that's because:

- `new Error().toString()` yields `"Error"`, and
- `parseInt("Error", 16)` yields `14` (because `0xE` is `14` and the parser stops at `r`).

On the other hand, `new Array()` does not trigger the same behavior because the `toString()` method of array objects returns the contents of the array, delimited by commas, not the class name. Therefore, `new Array().toString()` yields the empty string, and `parseInt()` subsequently yields `NaN`.

Comment: Ah, this makes perfect sense.  Thank you!